# Error in running ./stack.sh in devstack

Tags: stack, openstack, devstack

When I try to do ./stack.sh after the call trace I am provide with the following error :

```
`[Call Trace]
 ./stack.sh:217:source
 /home/work/devstack/stackrc:821:die
 [ERROR] /home/suramya/devstack/stackrc:821 Could not determine host ip address. See local.conf for suggestions on setting HOST_IP.
```

`

Answer (score 5):

After cloning:

- `cd devstack/`
- `cp samples/local.conf .`
- Edit the local.conf by adding the setting the HOST_IP of your machine on which devstack is being installed.

Answer (score 2):

Add `HOST_IP=<your machine ip address>` to local.conf file.

STEPS:

1. List item Go to the root folder where you cloned or copied "devstack". Like `/opt/stack/devstack`
2. Edit the "local.conf file. `vi local.conf`
3. Add `HOST_IP=0.0.0.0` (replace 0.0.0.0 with your machine IP address) to the file. Save and exit. The complete file will look like this:

   `[[local|localrc]]
   HOST_IP=13.84.214.151
   ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
   DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
   RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
   SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD`
4. Run `./stack.sh`

This should run without errors.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit this file "/opt/stack/devstack/stackrc"
2. In this file, find the HOST_IP Variable and change it to HOST_IP=0.0.0.0
3. Instead of 0.0.0.0, set your IP Address (ifconfig)

Answer (score 1):

First, get the IP address using the command:

`ip addr show`

Second, after you could get the IP address, copy and paste it in the local.conf file that you have created under the devstack directory, that should be looking like this:

```
[[local|localrc]]
HOST_IP=0.0.0.0   #replace 0.0.0.0 with your ip
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

then run `./stack.sh` again.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Find the IP Address](https://linuxquicktips.com/find-ip-address/)
2. Add HOST_IP=[IP_ADDRESS]
3. Make sure there is no space between the '=' and IP address in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

1. First check the IP address of your server interface by using command `ifconfig`.
2. Then find the line

`HOST_IP=$(get_default_host_ip "$FIXED_RANGE" "$FLOATING_RANGE" "$HOST_IP_IFACE" "$HOST_IP" "inet")` in the file */opt/stack/devstack/stackrc*.

Put your server IP (*in my setup line number is 859*), make sure the entry is like below:

**if [ "$HOST_IP" == "192.168.0.0" ];**

then save the file (suppose my server IPis *192.168.0.0*).

3. Run `./stack.sh`

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22.04, following the devstack tutorial here: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/
one only has this in local.conf :

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

In the VM I run ./stack.sh in, I determined the IP from a shell:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009:~/develop/devstack$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:e5:00:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 85917sec preferred_lft 85917sec
    inet6 fec0::dd5:3efa:4caf:756b/64 scope site temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86043sec preferred_lft 14043sec
    inet6 fec0::e0d0:2dd7:984b:e9a6/64 scope site dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86043sec preferred_lft 14043sec
    inet6 fe80::824d:ebd2:b04b:73ff/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The IP is 10.0.2.15.

I simply added that as the HOST_IP so local.conf looks like:
ubuntu@ubuntu-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009:~/develop/devstack$ cat local.conf

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
HOST_IP=10.0.2.15
```

Then run the command again and it passes the step.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set up the HOST_IP. It would be great if you can share your `local.conf` file for us to take a further look.

Take a look at this: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/

And there is a sample local.conf file under `/samples`

Comment: late, but see answer above. just add the HOST_IP line. Strange that such a simple thing is not taken care of by the script as a default, perhaps there is a reason.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to modify stackrc and set

```
HOST_IP=${HOST_IP:-192.168.227.1}
```

`192.168.227.1` is my IP, use your IP instead.